# Asp.net application giving error after deploying on IIS 8

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have created an Asp.Net application in VS 2012 and deployed it on IIS 8 server. But when I try to run the application it is throwing an error stating Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have been searching for the solution for last 2 days but the problem hasn't got solved. Please help. Thanks.

The detailed error message is as follows:

Server Error in '/OperatorSlip_deploy' Application.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   OperatorSlip.Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +84
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18449

Comment: restart your system then try again. I was facing the same issue then I had restart my system and the problem had resolved

Comment: In general, you should post the [relevant code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). However, I believe this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it.

Answer (score -1):

**Try this:**

You should add your website as an application under the default website or you set in the IIS to start from your website.

Comment: If my answer solves your problem,don't forget to mark it as an answer.For marking as answer : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work